# Node issue with Travis CI

Tags: node.js

I am trying to deploy my app using Travis CI. I've changed almost nothing since the last deploy, which went fine. When I deploy, the build fails and I get this message:

```
Installing deploy dependencies
Fetching: dpl-script-1.9.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed dpl-script-1.9.6
1 gem installed
!!! Script support is experimental !!!
dpl.2
Preparing deploy
dpl.3
Deploying application
node[7709]: ../src/node_contextify.cc:628:static void node::contextify::ContextifyScript::New(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&): Assertion `args[1]->IsString()' failed.
 1: node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x876c55 [node]
 3: node::contextify::ContextifyScript::New(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [node]
 4: v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(v8::internal::CallHandlerInfo*) [node]
 5: 0xacd2df [node]
 6: v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
 7: 0x32e75058427d
Script failed with status 
failed to deploy
```

Note: this does not happen when I start the application locally OR when I deploy to Heroku, as I had to do a moment ago as a backup. It ONLY happens with Travis CI.

This may be related: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/2162

I can't figure out how to fix this. I've done npm update. It seems like it might be something on the Travis side. Any thoughts?

Comment: Reading the Gulp issue you linked, it could be related the Node version that you make Travis run. What version do you run locally and what version have you defined for Travis?

Comment: Entire Travis file: 

language: node_js
node_js: node
cache:
  directories:
    - node_modules
script:
  - npm test
env:
  - CI=true

before_install:
  - gem update --remote bundler
  - gem update --system

before_deploy:
  - npm install netlify-cli -g
  - npm run build

deploy:
  provider: script
  script: netlify deploy -s $NETLIFY_SITE_ID -t $NETLIFY_ACCESS_TOKEN -p ./build
  skip_cleanup: true
  on:
    branch: master

Comment: What happens when you specify Node 8 in your travis file? See https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/javascript-with-nodejs/#Specifying-Node.js-versions? I'm just doing wild stabs in the dark based on the replies in the Github issue. Your problem could be completely unrelated, but its worth a try.

Comment: That worked. Node 10 was messing with it. I changed it to Node 8 and everything worked fine. I would mark this as the answer if it weren't a comment

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help :)